# what driver chip do i need for a irf4905 p-channel mosfet

Tags: p-channel

I'm trying to figure out what chips I need to run my irf4905. the mosfets will need to be running 5 amps at 24 volts using pwm to Varey the watts. if anyone has done anything with this mosfet an knows what drivers it need anything would help

Comment: Why do you think you need a driver Chip? Tell us more about the pwm.

Comment: Hi Sam, you're getting close votes because product recommendations are not allowed here. If you instead describe what you are doing in more detail, alternatives may be given. If you just want a PMOS driver, then search for these at your favorite distributor.

Comment: Actually, the close votes are for more details / clarity -- a schematic and more details would definitely help. This is nearly a product recommendation, too, but is not quite asking for a *specific* product (rather what specifications to look for) and therefore (arguably) on-topic on that front.

Answer (score 1):

FETs need a gate voltage >2 to >2.5 Vgs(th)max to guarantee low RdsOn. This is fundamental to all datasheets on FETs. The logic level types are Vgs(th)= Vt (aka) Vth ~ 1V for 3.3V operation.

Your choice of RdsOn depends on I^2*Ron losses, thermal resistance and prudent max junction temp rise << 40’C.

Inductive loads required an equivalent higher current rated diode in reverse across drain to rail-switched whether you choose Lo or hi side switch.